# Ownership of file(s) in directory with SGID bit set

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory that has the SGID bit set,
so `ls` displays it as `drwxr-sr-x`, and is owned by a normal user. 
I have a file that is owned by root in that directory, with permission 644.
 
The question is can I make that file become owned by the user-owner of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have read permissions of file, and write permission of directory. Therefore you can make a copy, remove original, rename copy to original name.

Comment: Thanks @ctrl-alt-delor. That is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

- I don’t know of any general, magical way
  of changing the ownership of an existing file. 
  If you want to change the owner of the file,
  you’ll have to `chown` it (as root, i.e., `sudo`).
- The SGID bit a directory has nothing to do with the *(user) ownership*
  of files in that directory. 
  It causes all *subsequently* (i.e., *future*) created files
  in that directory
  to have the same ***group*** ownership as the directory itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @G-Man